# Cloned a personal repo on work PC and authenticated with my login credentials - how to remove access?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I wanted to work on my personal project during my lunch break at work and decided to clone the repo.

The Git user on my work PC is configured with a different account so I was prompted to log in as my personal account. I typed in my credentials and the clone was successful. I did a couple of test commits and they correctly popped up with the author being my work account.

However, I can't figure out how to remove this access (I don't need to do that right now, but I am just wondering). I tried setting the work account's access as READ only but I could still commit changes...

Is it a simple as deleting the local repo from my work PC?

Comment: I think you can find some nice info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/5475880

Comment: The solution provided in your link worked (I just removed my personal account credentials from Windows Credentials Manager). Upon trying to push, I was prompted to log in again. Thanks.